# Clickable widget is not working after a while

Tags: android, android-widget

I have setup the clickable event for the widget like below but the widget will not be clickable after like 7 or 8 hours.

This is the view `wording_widget.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Widget.MyWordingApp.AppWidget.Container"
    android:id="@+id/widgetBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyWordingApp.AppWidgetContainer">
  <TextView/>
  <TextView/>
```

This is the widget logic:

```
public class WordingWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    WordDBHelper dbHelper;
    private static String UPDATE = "UPDATE";

    private void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.wording_widget);
        updateWords(context, views);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetBox, getPendingSelfIntent(context, UPDATE));
        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, WordingWidget.class);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.wording_widget);
        updateWords(context, remoteViews);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
    }
}

private void updateWords(Context context, RemoteViews views) {
    dbHelper = WordDBHelper.getInstance(context);
    //get strings from db and update the views
}

protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
}
```

Even though `remoteView` has been set the onlick event but why it stops working after a while? When I click the widget, `onRecevie()` is not called anymore.